# Algebra find determinant based on other matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

[I've no idea how to solve this, can somebody please help me? I'm quite confusing to find the determinant based on other matrix @.@](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9r8ak.png)

[image]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9r8ak.png

Comment: can you see the picture of the question?

Comment: Do you know how the determinant changes when you do various operations on the matrix? For example, if you multiply a column by $c$, what happens to the determinant? What happens to the determinant when you replace the sum of the third column by the sum of the second and third columns? If you know these properties, then all you need to do is do operations to transform the original matrix to the new matrix, and keep track of how each operation changes the determinant.

Comment: ya i know, but the question is seems like not as easy as just multiple a value, it feel like row minus row something, so i feel very weird about the question

Comment: Much better if you write out the question here, not make people chase things offsite.

Comment: i actually got post the picture of the question, but i dont kno why it doesn't appear. But i dont know how to write a matrix here

Comment: @MelvinChong `dont know how to write a matrix here` See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5023).